# Java Object Array to JTree

Tags: java, object, arraylist, jtree

I have a

```
Class Category 
private Category parent;
private String name;
private ArrayList<Category> categories;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
```

and an

```
ArrayList<Category> categories
```

the ArrayList contains

```
[0]Categorie #1
   parent = null
   name = asdasd
   ArrayList<Category> categories
      [0]Categorie #2
          parent = #1
          name = asdasddsa
          ArrayList<Category> categories
              [0]Categories #4
                  parent = #2 
                  name = asdasdasd
                  ArrayList<Category> categories = null
      [1]Categorie #3
          parent = #1
          name = asdasdasdasdasd
          ArrayList<Category> categories = null
```

and i want to create a JTree out of that ArrayList. 
I tried it with a function that uses itself until the categories ArrayList was null but 
with this method i couldn't have more than 1 category in the parent categorie.

I created these functions but they don't work.

```
public void generateNodes(Category category,DefaultMutableTreeNode root){
    ArrayList<Use> usages = category.getUsages();
    for(Use use: usages){
        category.getNode().add(use.getNode());
    }
    if(!category.getCategories().isEmpty()){
        root.add(category.getNode());

        for(Category cat: category.getCategories()){
            generateNodes(cat, category.getNode());
        }

    }else{
        root.add(category.getNode());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a recursive method. Every Category you come across, create a DefaultMutableTreeNode, then add the properties as child nodes. Then recursively call method with the contained Cateogories.

If you want to have more than one category as the root parent, you should make a 'fake' root node, then call this on JTree :

**setRootVisible(false);**

Its still one tree, but it looks like many. Is that what you meant?

Your code should look something like this :

```
public void generateNodes(Category categories,DefaultMutableTreeNode root){
        ArrayList<Use> usages = categ.getUsages();
        for(Use use: usages){
            categ.getNode().add(use.getNode());
        }
        if(!categ.getCategories().isEmpty()){
            root.add(categ.getNode());

            for(Category cat: categ.getCategories(){
                generateNodes(categ, root);
            }

        }else{
            root.add(categ.getNode());
        }

}
```

Comment: i added the functions i created if you want to take a look at them

Comment: you need to pass in root into the second method as well : private void generateNodes(ArrayList<Category> categories, root)

Comment: the root needs to go into the second message, so that it can get any DefaultMutableTreeNodes that are created in the recursive method

Comment: actually you only need the first method, and its signature should be : public void generateNodes(Category categorie,DefaultMutableTreeNode root){

Comment: I added code to my original answer. You need ONE method not the TWO. And it should look like my example (I dont have IDE so i cant check it)

Comment: with your function i get a StackOverflowError/endless loop

Comment: ok named a variable wrong thank you for your help it works now